# Input tag with datepicker in a <td> the button appears underneath the input tag instead of next to it

Tags: php, jquery, html, datepicker

If I place an input tag with a datepicker attached to it, inside a html table  cell, the datepicker-button appears underneath the input tag, but I want it next to it. How can that be done?
The widths of the  or the  tags don't have any influence, nor the character size.

**PHP code**

```
<?php
  $startdate="02-01-2014";
  if ($_POST['submit']=='Save') {
    $startdate=$_POST['date1'];
    $startdate1=$startdate;
  }
?>
```

**HTML code**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>starting date:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="dp1" name="date1" placeholder="starting date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $startdate; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$( "#dp1" ).datepicker();
$( "#dp1" ).datepicker( "option",{
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    showAnim: "show",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonPosition: "right",
    beforeShow: function(){    
        $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 10)}
    });

    //setting the initial date of dp1 to $startdate:
    $( "#dp1" ).datepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo $startdate ?>");
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please? so we can help you.

Comment: Do your `td` elements or container elements have a fixed width? When I try the code as is, the button appears next to the input tag. Could you provide a fiddle where the problem is reproduced?

Comment: The problem seems to be the combination with the bootstrap css. You could try and find the offending css and override it, but there also datetimepicker plugins for bootstrap you could try out.

Comment: That is certainly it! Thanks, I'll try the Bootstrap equivalent instead.

Comment: Also did some testing, problem seems to be a combination of input being set to display block and width 100%. Theoretically an overriding css of `td > input[type="text"]
{
    display: inline;
     width: auto;
}` would solve it, but going the bootstrap way is indeed best :)